# How handle TimeoutError in celery

Tags: python, celery

I use several `task.apply_async()` and `task.get()` to make asynch calls to the server and make the client wait for results. These tasks can take variable time to return a result that goes from 1 minute, to 3 minutes to complete.

I want to detect when a task got a `TimeError` because the server was down and the request couldn't be handled, or delivered. Using the timeout on `apply_async` call is the only way to handle these errors? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the call get. It has get(timeout=value)

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Worker side

To handle time **worker side** use soft/hard timelimit: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits

It will raise an error if the task exceed the limit. Then you can catch this exception:

```
try:
    task.apply_async().get()
except TimeLimitExceeded as err:
    pass
```

2. Client side

To catch TimeError on client side, use get(timeout=value) as explained.

```
try:
  task.apply_async().get(timeout=90)
except TimeoutError as err:
   pass
```

Comment: from celery import  exceptions

try:
    task_data = task_result.get(timeout=ASYNC_RESULT_GET_TIMEOUT)
except exceptions.TimeoutError:
    ...